# Instantiating TypeScript generic class without specifying type

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

If I create a generic class

```
class Generic<T> {
     prop: T;
}
```

It won't allow me to type something without specifying `T` in the type

```
// Generic type 'Generic<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
const val: Generic = new Generic();
```

But if I use type inference, it doesn't complain, it lets me instantiate it

```
const val = new Generic();
// field prop is not of type any, we can't access any properties on it
// val.prop.anything -> Compiler error
// val.prop.toString() -> No error, is it a string?
// val.prop.length -> Compiler error, not a string, just assumes that everything has a toString (based on boxing)
```

Is this behavior specified? What is the reasoning behind this?

**Background**

Angular2 has an `EventEmitter` which requires a type of the argument for the event. However, for some events, you don't pass any arguments, in which case we had been using `EventEmitter<void>`. However, I just noticed that you can just define emitters without specifying type and `new EventEmitter()` works. The drawback of this approach is that the compiler won't complain if you pass an argument to `emitter.emit('something')`. This is not what I'm interested in, just background so readers can understand where the question came from.

**Playground**
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Generic%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20val%3A%20Generic%20%3D%20new%20Generic()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20val2%20%3D%20new%20Generic()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aval2.prop.test%20%3D%201%3B

Comment: Since generics are not available at run time (it will all become pure Javascript), I can imagine that the `new Generic()` line is allowed since you might use exactly this line in Javascript that imports a transpiled library. In short: for compatibility to Javascript.

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? I get an error when try to compile your code. `Generic type 'Generic<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).`

Comment: @Sebastian I can't make sense out of what you're saying... Any links that validate your thoughts? If that's allowed, now you have a property without a type, that doesn't seem to be compatible with JavaScript because you'd have to cast `prop` to be something if you want to use it?

Comment: @Duncan I'm using the online playground, I would assume it's latest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following two statements are equivalent...

```
const val: Generic<{}> = new Generic();
const val2 = new Generic();
```

In the first case, the type argument that is omitted on the right-hand side is inferred from the type on the left-hand side.

In the second case, you end up with an object type, because nothing more specific can be inferred.

The rule here is that the type of the variable *must* have the generic type parameter satisfied. When you use `const val: Generic = new Generic();` the type parameter is not satisfied - you can't ask for it to be inferred because you have decided to annotate the variable.

So the two allowable scenarios are:

1. Specify the (entire) type yourself with a type annotation
2. Allow the (entire) type to be inferred by the compiler

To make your later example work, you have two options.

Option 1... if you really don't want to limit the type, go dynamic...

```
const val2 = new Generic<any>();
val2.prop.test = 1;
```

Or... Option 2... if you *do* want to limit the type, specify it.

```
const val2 = new Generic<{ test: number }>();
val2.prop.test = 1;
```

And finally, in many contexts, you don't need to specify the type argument as it can be inferred contextually.

Comment: const val: Generic<string> = new Generic<string>(); ?

Comment: He could also make it default to `any`, that way it doesn't have to be specified explicitly. `class Generic<T = any> { ... }`

Comment: @JeffMercado For my specific case, that will stop throwing errors when people pass an argument to the emit call  `emitter.emit('what') // should throw error`